# amcl jumped very much with debug infomation "Time jumped forward by [...] for timer of period [...] ...."

Tags: ros, navigation, time, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use robot_pose_ekf to fuse odom and imu to get a more accurate tf(`from odom to base_footprint`),and then let amcl use  this tf to provide a tf(`from map to base_footprint`). And when i see the  amcl wiki , it tells me we should use `diff-corrected` odom model. I also  use `likelihood_field_prob`laser model to  let amcl  not use the scans which hit  unexpected obstacles such human beings  ,when localizing  robot with laser  on the global map . In rviz ,when  i see amcl provides `particle_cloud`,it is more converged than old models(`diff mode and likelihood_field` laser model), very excited and thankful!!!!

- But  sometimes  when robot is moving and all particle_cloud is converged( in free map areas ,there is no particle),let us mark this time is `t_k`time. Suddenly the particle_cloud is little converged than `t_k` time ,but it still has some particles converged  in  robot footprint and  in map free areas,  there also appears some particles.let mark this time is `t_k+1`time. This is [t_k+1.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs7wvbh7akbmccx/t_k%2B1.jpg?dl=0).  when `t_k+2`time ,robot pose in map  jumped very much. It jumped in some should not be place, and  the amcl output particle_cloud are all converged in  robot footprint, it is weird!!!,This is [t_k+2.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8gx07ve2hejm4h/t_k%2B2.jpg?dl=0).
- when i `rosbag record` all the  topics and `rosbag play` them , `rqt_plot` the robot_pose_ekf pose data(i write a node to get robot pose in odom  ) and amcl output  pose data  to watch whether it because robot_pose_ekf data  occured .  But when i see rivz and `rqt_plot`,when amcl position jumped ,robot_pose_ekf position data  did not jump. I guess  this  is not odom, imu and  robot_pose_ekf' s problem. This is [amcl_jumped_data_analysis.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0fe5lr9r8rvim24/amcl_jumped_data_analysis.png?dl=0),ans its [zoomed out png1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3j0h9auszjiqsn/amcl_jumped_data_analysis1.png?dl=0),[zoomed out png2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtwjauqlx3lk84q/amcl_jumped_data_analysis2.png?dl=0)
- This is [amcl_jump_video.mp4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8hgy8qnoitrdjz/amcl_jump.mp4?dl=0) , [amcl_jump.bag](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wblgyww3w458qh6/amcl_jumped.bag?dl=0) ,  [package:to convert_orientation2Yaw_And_get_pose_ekf_position](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2nuy82gxaii333/convert_orientation2Yaw_And_get_pose_ekf_position.tar.gz?dl=0)  and [default.rviz config file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zuf6ad4uwbi55kd/default.rviz?dl=0)
- when i let amcl node logger level is Debug,  i see some print  useful information such as `"Time jumped forward by [0.364688] for timer of period [0.010000], resetting timer (current=946684907.876552),next _expected=946684907.511864"`[Dubug infos: Time jumped forward.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhc3mqlo5gpnzek/time%20jumped.jpg?dl=0)
- Does amcl jumped because this message ??  how can i fixed this problem??
- Any advice will be appreciated and thanks you very very much!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251689/amcl-jumped-very-much--with-debug-infomation-%22time-jumped-forward-by-%5B...%5D-for-timer-of-period-%5B...%5D-....%22/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when amcl's particle_cloud is converged(robot is moving ),next time ,if  particle_cloud  become the  [t_k+1.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs7wvbh7akbmccx/t_k%2B1.jpg?dl=0),and next time particles converged to wrong place .This werid  phenomenon occured because when amcl  take resample  ,if  the   `<param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.001"/>`and  `<param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.1"/> (in AMCL.cfg )` , resample will  take some random particles and  take  some particles  proportional to  latest moment' particles weight .[Link is here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/amcl/src/amcl/pf/pf.c#L365).`So to resolve this ,set the two params all zeros` .The reason i will  read the probobalistic robotics book.

---

Originally posted by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) with karma: 252 on 2017-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2